# Filtered Search Using 2 List Box

Tags: php, mysql

Good day!

I am having trouble with filtered search in PHP. This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="index.php" action="get">
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true">
<label>Product
<select name="product">
<option value="Product 1">Product 1</option>
<option value="Product 2">Product 2</option>
<option value="Product 3">Product 3</option>
<option value="Product 4">Product 4</option>
<option value="Product 5">Product 5</option>
</select>
</label>

<label>City
<select name="city">
    <option value="Sample City 1">Sample City 1</option>
    <option value="Sample City 2">Sample City 2</option>
    <option value="Sample City 3">Sample City 3</option>
</select>
</label>

<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

As you can see I have two list box that will serve as the both the category for the search.
And here is my PHP code for the search:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

require("connect.php");

$product = $_GET['product'];
$city = $_GET['city'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM records";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Could not connect to database"); 

echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['store'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['city'];
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}
```

* This PHP is right after the form of my HTML.
What I basically need to do is show the results in the database that matches both of the categories.

And here is what my database looks like:
[image]

My products1 - products5 are set sa TINYINT because from what I've read about TINYINT is that any value aside from 0 is considered as TRUE and 0 is FALSE.

My actual goal is to display only the records that will match the categories the user sets.
If the user set the PRODUCTS category to PRODUCT 1 and the CITY category to SAMPLE CITY 4, it will then check if PRODUCT 1 is 0=NOT AVAILABLE or 1=AVAILABLE in SAMPLE CITY 4. And as follows, if it is available then it will display the name of the STORE where it can be found.

But on this specific line in my PHP code:
    $query = "SELECT * FROM records";
I am having trouble when trying to modify it. Example:
    $query = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE $product = '$city'";
It shows my die() message.

Is there any other way I could accomplish this in a much simpler way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Actually, that should be `die(mysqli_error($con))` - OP is using `mysqli_`

Comment: No error message but no data is being shown.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry.... my eyes only see what i  think :D thanks .. And User3627135 your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection in case you are not aware

Comment: Your column is called `product1` yet you're using `<option value="Product 1">` where it should be `<option value="product1">` etc. - Also add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя You're welcome, I get those too; believe me ;)

Comment: @user3627135 So, any luck?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the error reporting. I have tried your suggestion about renaming all the values in my list boxes and the errors when I'm tweaking my query is gone. Thank you. All need now is to configure how to show the proper results. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

 require("connect.php");

 $product = $_GET['product'];
 $city = $_GET['city'];

 $column_name =  preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strtolower($product));

 $query = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE $column_name = 1 and city = '$city'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Could not connect to database"); 

 echo "<table>";

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo $row['store'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $row['city'];
  echo "</td></tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>";
}
```

I think it help for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, kind sir. But I am getting an undefined variable error on $str.

Comment: Sorry My mistake :(. Please chack now. replace $str by $product.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply, sir. After changing $str with $product, I could not connect to my database. :(